# BigQuery View ETL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery

We have the following data flow [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sN6z.jpg).

In our internal system 1 we have a BigQuery WH and we are exposing the data with a View 1.

This view is the used to ingest data in the system then its processed and exposing the data with another View 2.

We want to know if its possible to ingest the external BI system 3 (3rd party tool) with the data in View 2, because we found the following limitations in the BQ Views [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#view_limitations).

Also we found that is possible to share the data with an [Authorized View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro#authorized_views).

The external BI system 3 has a Service Account attached to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new contributor I recommend you to take some time and read the following: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: ingest data is possible. The SQL  `insert` is a DML-command and therefore not possible in views, but in direct queries. Another option is to use the REST-API.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel do you have any detailed information regarding the REST API for BQ that can be used with the views?

Comment: Is the problem that the tool doesn't have permission to access the underlying data, so the view is off limits too?  You could always materialize the view by a scheduled query which would be a table with completely different permissioning.

Comment: @Mike I guess the access is not the issue.
'@'Vicente 
Again a view cannot change the underlaying data such as adding rows by insert. There are other options to change/insert data. REST API, python etc. is way to upload data. Please name your (3rd party tool) which should insert data to BigQuery. Check if the tool can use REST API to upload data. If not and only DML is possible, it has to access BigQuery directly without any views for that.

Comment: Bajaware is the 3rd party tool that needs to access the data shown in the view